# List all packages that depend on a certain package with pacman

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I have two packages which are in conflict after installing a new one with pacman on arch.

How can I list all installed packages that are depending on the ones in conflict?

Or more general:
**How can I list all installed packages that are depending on a certain other package**

Comment: It might help give more hints if you mention the package name.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To list the dependencies use `pacman -Si` (i.e., `pacman --sync --info`)
or `pacman -Qi` (i.e., `pacman --query --info`).

To list the reverse dependencies: `pacman -Sii` (i.e., `pacman --sync --info --info`; yes two infos).

Arch Linux: [Querying package dependencies](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta#Querying_package_dependencies)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the ArchWiki regarding querying local packages:  The `-Qi` flag will also list any packages on your system dependent on the package.  E.g. `pacman -Qi <package name> | grep 'Required By'` returns a list of packages dependent on the queried package. In this case, adding the second `i` seemingly does not produce any relevant difference.

Comment: Also, from what I can tell: `pacman -Sii <package> | 'Required By'` will list any packages in the *official* repo dependent on the package, but seemingly not other packages, such as packages in AUR. If you want to see what packages installed on your system that depends the package, especially if you have packages from utside the official repo, `pacman -Qi ...`  is probably the better option.

Comment: @PålBjartan The second `-i` doesn't seem to produce any relevant difference. See [the description](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/pacman/pacman.8.en#QUERY_OPTIONS_(APPLY_TO_-Q)) and also try this `diff -u <(pacman -Qi openssl) <(pacman -Qii openssl)`.

Answer (score 18):

> How can I list all installed packages that are depending on a certain other package

For one level dependency use `pacman -Qi package_name | grep 'Depends On'`

e.g:

```bsh
$ pacman -Qi jack | grep 'Depends On'
Depends On      : alsa-lib  db  glibc  gcc-libs  libsamplerate  libzita-alsa-pcmi.so=0-64  libzita-resampler.so=1-64
```

To view the dependency tree of a package use `pactree` which is owned by `pacman-contrib`

e.g:

```bsh
$ pactree jack
jack
├─alsa-lib
│ ├─glibc
│ │ ├─linux-api-headers provides linux-api-headers>=4.10
│ │ ├─tzdata
│ │ └─filesystem
│ │   └─iana-etc
│ ├─alsa-topology-conf
│ └─alsa-ucm-conf
├─db
│ ├─gcc-libs
│ │ └─glibc provides glibc>=2.27
│ └─bash provides sh
│   ├─readline provides readline>=7.0
│   │ ├─glibc
│   │ ├─ncurses
│   │ │ ├─glibc
│   │ │ └─gcc-libs
│   │ └─ncurses provides libncursesw.so=6-64
│   ├─glibc
│   └─ncurses
├─glibc
├─gcc-libs
├─libsamplerate
│ └─glibc
├─zita-alsa-pcmi provides libzita-alsa-pcmi.so=0-64
│ ├─alsa-lib
│ ├─gcc-libs
│ └─glibc
└─zita-resampler provides libzita-resampler.so=1-64
  ├─gcc-libs
  └─glibc
```

To view the dependent tree of a package, pass the reverse flag `-r` to `pactree`

Comment: Simple list of packages used: `pactree <pkg-name> -lu`, useful for reinstaling: `pacman -S $(pactree <pkg-name> -lu)`

Comment: @bodolsog: then you can just use -u because it already implies -l

Comment: That's not what the OP asked.  He asked list the packages that depend ON a particular package. Not to list all the packages that that particular package depends on.

Comment: It's actually only the last sentence of the answer that answers OP's question. I suggest you put this at the top of your comment.

Answer (score 5):

For multiple level dependencies use `pactree` a command that comes with `pacman` package.
With the option `-r` you can find the top application/packages that depend on a given package.

Here an example:

```
pactree -r gst-plugins-bad-libs
gst-plugins-bad-libs
├─gst-plugins-bad
│ ├─cheese
│ └─gnome-video-effects
│   └─cheese
├─gtk4
│ ├─gnome-desktop-4
│ │ └─xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
│ │   └─xdg-desktop-portal
│ │     └─flatpak
│ └─libadwaita
│   └─xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
└─libcheese
  └─cheese
```

In this case the top applications are `flatpak` and `cheese`

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it is just e.g. `sudo pacman --remove python2` then you will see:

```
$ sudo pacman --remove python2    
[sudo] password for elijah:                                                     
checking dependencies...                                                       
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)          
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by cython2            
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-appdirs    
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-cairo      
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-click      
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-colorama   
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-fasteners  
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-funcsigs   
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-giturlparse
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-gobject    
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-gobject2   
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-linecache2 
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-mock       
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-monotonic  
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-numpy      
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-ordered-set
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-pyparsing  
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-pypdf2     
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-pyxdg      
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-setuptools 
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-sh         
:: removing python2 breaks dependency 'python2' required by python2-yaml       
 -> exit status 1
```

I noticed that with `pacman --sync --info --info` it was showing me every package that depended on it, not necessarily the ones on my system, I think.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers are incorrect. If you want to know which packages depend on package X, use the following command:

```
pacman -Qi | grep -E 'Depends On|Name' | grep -B 1 -E 'Depends On.*PACKAGE_X.*' | grep Name | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Some existing answers [are wrong](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/565968/106752) as they are not searching reverse dependency, some others are missing some details that [may cause confusion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/565955/106752), and [some](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/740895/106752) are not using `pacman` which is what the OP asked for, although I personally like the answer as it gives the right answer. After some minutes of reading and searching, this is what I could gather:

Assume we have a package named "X" and we want to see which packages depend on X. Now we have two conditions:

1. If you do not have the package X installed and just want to get the info from the repos, you can use `pacman -Sii X`
2. If you have it installed (which this is what answers the OP's question), you should use `pacman -Qi X`

In both of the commands above, you should look the `Required By:` and `Optional For:` fields. The following is example of `highway-git` which is required by `libjxl`:

```
❯ pacman -Qi highway-git
Name            : highway-git
Version         : 1.0.4.r256.g89c0310-1
Description     : A C++ library for SIMD (Single Instruction, Multiple Data) (git version)
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://github.com/google/highway/
Licenses        : Apache
Groups          : None
Provides        : highway
Depends On      : gcc-libs
Optional Deps   : None
Required By     : libjxl
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : highway
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 5.45 MiB
Packager        : Unknown Packager
Build Date      : Wed 31 May 2023 11:33:59 AM EEST
Install Date    : Wed 31 May 2023 11:36:16 AM EEST
Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : None
```

It worth mentioning that the `pacman -Sii X` does not work if the X is an AUR package, but `pacman -Qi X` does work on AUR because it is already installed and the info exists on your computer.

For further reading you can go to [Arch wiki for Pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman/Rosetta#Querying_package_dependencies). The info above is very briefly mentioned in the first row of the table (at least at the time of writing this answer).

Comment: There seems to be [no point](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/pacman/pacman.8.en#QUERY_OPTIONS_(APPLY_TO_-Q)) in second `-i` with `-Q`. Try e.g. `diff -u <(pacman -Qi openssl) <(pacman -Qii openssl)`.

Comment: @x-yuri Thanks for bringing this up and also providing a working example. You are right, there is not difference in the manual, but in action I can see a difference. the single `-i` does now show `Backup Files` where as the `-ii` does. But this is besides the point as we are interested in `Required By` field. I will update the post to reflect this.

Comment: Actually there is a difference in the [man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/pacman/pacman.8.en#QUERY_OPTIONS_(APPLY_TO_-Q)): "Passing two --info or -i flags will also display the list of backup files and their modification states." But yeah, that's of no concern here. UPD. But if you meant the Arch wiki page, then `-Qii` can be replaced with `-Qi` there I believe.

Answer (score 0):

`pactree` is a good tool to print reverse dependencies. If you want to reduce the output you can set the `-d` flag to set the *depth*,e.g.:

```
pactree -r -d 1 jack
```